# How to tell tomcat to deploy to different locations (vitual hosts)?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, path

I want to have tomcat put different webapps to different folders on my server.
Reason is: I am using (test phase) different virtual hosts and therefore I want to seperate the access to them, too.
Lets say:

> vhost1.mydomain.com accesses locally at /home/vhost1/webapps/app1
>
> vhost2.mydomain.com accesses locally at /home/vhost2/webapps/app2

BTW: I am only concerned about the deployed path, the war file could stay where ever tomcat wants to have it.
This is because I want to let different users access my deployed content, but not all tomcat webapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about having the deployed path separate from the war file, but you can certainly have different deployment locations for different URLs.

Edit the (tomcat home)/conf/server.xml

Find the <host> element:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
      unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
      xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

   <!-- other stuff -->
</Host>
```

name should be changed to the URL, e.g. vhost1.mydomain.com
appBase can be an absolute path on your filesystem where it will look for WAR files to deploy

You can have multiple <host> entries, all with different name and appBase.

Comment: I follwed your suggestion, but for some reason my new /webapps folder for my 2nd domain does not work. I can access http://vhost2.mydomain.com:8080 but end up in an empty response ... I tried to check access rights but they seem to be alright.

Comment: can you post the &lt;host&gt: entries from your server.xml? Also, are your DNS records set up correctly?

Comment: NickJ, thank you very much for willing to help me. I found out that I have at least a permission problem. I am using CentOS. The tomcat manager is running and able to deploy. A look to the file system shows that the war file was unpacked in the correct folder. But if I want to access my web app, I receive "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(2,0) The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application". Very strange! Either still an access right problem or I missed s.th. else which I did not understand.